# Object constructor parameters: existing Array variable vs [] literal

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want to make the following comparison:

```
Object([]) === []; //false, as expected.
```

If now I assign an empty array to a variable, we now have:

```
const myArr = [];
Object(myArr) === myArr; //true
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: In the first snippet you have `[]` twice, thus you have created two distinct arrays. In the second snippet you have `[]` once, thus you have only one array and you are comparing it to itself.

Comment: Calling `Object()` does nothing but return its argument in both cases. The first case is equivalent to `[] === []`, which is false. The second case is equivalent to `myArr === myArr` which is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`===` checks if both the objects refers to the same thing. i.e. refers to the same memory location. When you are doing `Object([]) === [];` then JS runtime creates 2 different memory location one for `[]` in left hand side and one for Right hand side `[]`. Hence they are unequal.

In the 2nd case in R.H.S and in L.H.S `myArr` refers to the same memory location. And and when you call object constructor with myArr, `Object(myArr)` it does nothing , constructor is empty. object reference are still unchanged hence they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Because `[] === []` is `false`.

`===` compare references. Every time you do `[]`, you create a new object in the memory, and naturally they have different references. So `===` gives you false.

`Object(Array)` gives you the same object that you give in. So when you do `Object([])`, you get the same object you give in, but it doesn't have the same reference with the object on the right-hand side. When you do `Object(myArr) === myArr`, both operands have the same reference, so it evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

An array in Javascript is an instance of Object:

```
> [] instanceof Object
true
```

Object, in turn, is referential type. So whenever two objects are compared, they are compared by reference, not by value. So calling `Object` with any array (or another object) as the first argument casts the latter into a reference to itself, hence true.

Same with plain-objects or any other objects:

```
> const object = {};
undefined
> Object(object) === object;
true
> const array = [];
undefined
> Object(array) === array;
true
> const map = new Map()
undefined
> Object(map) === map;
true
> const set = new Set();
undefined
> Object(set) === set;
true
```

You could as well do this trick with strings and numbers:

```
> const string = new String('abc')
undefined
> string instanceof Object;
true
> Object(string) === string;
true
> const number = new Number(123);
undefined
> Object(number) === number;
true
```

This, of course, wouldn't work with primitive string and number types because they are not instances of Object:

```
> const primitiveNumber = 123;
undefined
> primitiveNumber instanceof Object;
false
> primitiveNumber instanceof Number;
false
> Object(primitiveNumber) === primitiveNumber;
false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your first line, you're comparing two different things, because you created two empty arrays. So because they're different, this returns `false`:

```
Object([]) === [];
```

---

However, in your other lines of code;

```
const myArr = [];
Object(myArr) === myArr;
```

You're comparing something to itself, which always evaluates to `true` (except `NaN`).